# How to omit the first result in the query fetching column names?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jsp

I'm fetching column names from a specific table:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND 
      table_name = " + "'" + SQL_RPL_TABLE_NAME + "'";
```

There is a placeholder for table name. The first column is usually the ID which I don't need to fetch as it should insert itself automatically in my table. But I really need the other column names based on the table name. How to do it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would add:

```
and ordinal_position > 1
```

This is the enumeration of the column positions.

Comment: You might also want to add an `ORDER BY ordinal_position` if you want columns in defined order.